# Showing attribute table in form using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table

Is there any way to show the attribute table of a layer in a `QTextBrowser` or a `QTableView` on form?

I did this but, (shows attribute table in a separate dialog) I have no idea, how to show it in my form.

```
iface.showAttributeTable(iface.activeLayer)
```

Answer (score 4):

QGIS 2.2 has a table model that you can use for a QTableView.  Use it like this:

```
cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(layer, 10000)
model = QgsAttributeTableModel(cache)
model.loadLayer()
table = QTableView()
table.setModel(model)
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I tried this but it shows nothing. I'm very new to qgis and python,so I don't know what should I do to show the attribute table in my QTableView. Please help me to do it.

Comment: QGIS 2.16 crashes when trying to apply this to a plugin tableview.  But it only crashes when I try to use .show()

Answer (score -2):

I am using a button to get current layers from canvas in my [qgis2leaf plugin](https://github.com/Geolicious/qgis2leaf) like this:

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
        allLayers = canvas.layers()
        for i in allLayers:
            if i.type() == 2:
                print(i.name() + " skipped as it is not a vector layer nor a raster layer")  
            if i.type() < 2: 
                self.ui.listWidget.addItem(i.name())
```

what you can do: do another loop over the layer and get all attributes. with

```
attributes = i.getFeatures()
```

and print them in another listwidget in your GUI.

Comment: The user wants to show the attribute table in their form not a list layers or features.