# Show attribute table in the form (table of contents)

Tags: qgis, python

I am building a plugin in a new window with table of contents associated. I have some actions, for example, zoom to extent and others and I want also to show the attribute table.

I search and find help in here [How to show attribute table in the form](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102386/how-to-show-attribute-table-in-the-form), with this little code:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QTableView
from qgis.gui import QgsAttributeTableModel
cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(self.view.currentLayer(), 10000)
model = QgsAttributeTableModel(cache)
model.loadLayer()
table = QTableView()
table.setModel(model)   
table.show()
```

But this code doesn't show anything. Could you help me to understand what is wrong?