# QGIS QgsAttributeTableModel only loads when called without a function in Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, pyqt

I tried to load QgsAttributeTableModel into QgsAttributeTableView or a plain Qt QTableView but it could run from inside a class method or function but it runs without any function or method. Below is the code that doesn't work.

This one works...

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTableView, QDialog, QVBoxLayout
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayerCache
from qgis.gui import (QgsAttributeTableModel,
                      QgsAttributeTableView,
                      QgsAttributeTableFilterModel)
import qgis.utils
layer = iface.activeLayer()
if not layer is None:
    canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
    vector_layer_cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(layer, 10000)
    attribute_table_model = QgsAttributeTableModel(vector_layer_cache)
    attribute_table_model.loadLayer()

    attribute_table_filter_model = QgsAttributeTableFilterModel(
        canvas,
        attribute_table_model
    )
    attribute_table_view = QgsAttributeTableView()
    attribute_table_view.setModel(attribute_table_filter_model)
    dialog = QDialog(iface.mainWindow())
    attribute_table_view.setParent(dialog)
    layout = QVBoxLayout(dialog)
    layout.addWidget(attribute_table_view)
    dialog.resize(800,600)
    dialog.show()
```

But this one doesn't

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTableView, QDialog, QVBoxLayout
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayerCache
from qgis.gui import (QgsAttributeTableModel,
                      QgsAttributeTableView,
                      QgsAttributeTableFilterModel)
import qgis.utils

def open_attr_table(layer):
    if not layer is None:
        canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
        vector_layer_cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(layer, 10000)
        attribute_table_model = QgsAttributeTableModel(vector_layer_cache)
        attribute_table_model.loadLayer()

        attribute_table_filter_model = QgsAttributeTableFilterModel(
            canvas,
            attribute_table_model
        )
        attribute_table_view = QgsAttributeTableView()

        attribute_table_view.setModel(attribute_table_filter_model)
        dialog = QDialog(iface.mainWindow())
        attribute_table_view.setParent(dialog)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(dialog)
        layout.addWidget(attribute_table_view)
        dialog.resize(800,600)
        dialog.show()
layer = iface.activeLayer()
open_attr_table(layer)
```

Both codes are identical. The only difference is, one runs inside a function, the other doesn't. I have tested them in QGIS 2.8 and 2.14.

I am wondering if QGIS has disabled the use of QgsAttributeTableFilterModel and QgsAttributeTableModel in QGIS plugins. Is there anything I should do to fix this issue?

Similar issues with no solution

[show-attribute-table-in-the-form-table-of-contents](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180802/show-attribute-table-in-the-form-table-of-contents)

[how-to-show-attribute-table-in-the-form](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180802/show-attribute-table-in-the-form-table-of-contents)

Comment: `dialog` is going out of scope when the function ends, `show()` isn't blocking so the function, runs, shows the dialog, ends, and delete the dialog instance.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It is now working when using dialog.exec_() But could you please explain more on why show is not working and a workaround as dialog will block the rest of the interface when using exec.