# Show only some attribute values in a table using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

From [Showing attribute table in form using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102386/showing-attribute-table-in-form-using-pyqgis) I know how to show a table with all the attributes using this code:

```
cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(layer, 10000)
model = QgsAttributeTableModel(cache)
model.loadLayer()
table = QTableView()
table.setModel(model)
```

Now I'm wondering how to show not all the attributes, but only the ones I want or, if it's possible, do the same thing with the classic attribute table.

Comment: You can set a filter expression to show only those records that meet the filter. Are you interested in that?

Comment: Hi thanks! Maybe yes. If, for example, In my attribute table I have three columns: ID, NAME and TABLE and I want to show only ID and TABLE what expression should I use? And how to use it in PyQGIS?

Comment: Your answer in this question can be another solution to my problem, but I'm not sure that this can work in QGIS 3 because I tried it and nothing happened https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215946/hide-column-in-attribute-table-by-using-pyqgis

Comment: Ah, OK. So, you actually need to hide columns (attributes), not records. Then you can use the answer you mentioned, right. Just tested it using QGIS v3.10 and it worked for me. After running the code snippet, open the attribute table in QGIS (or use `iface.showAttributeTable(my_layer)`) and you'll see some columns are now hidden.

Comment: Thanks, sorry if I wasn't clear. I have just another problem. When I select another style using layer.loadNamedStyle(selectedStyle) all columns are shown again. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: The style is removing the hidden property for the columns. So, you either adjust the style to keep those columns hidden or you call a function that hides them automatically after setting the style. If you agree, I'll mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I need to set the style after, but I'll try to adjust the style. Thank you you can sure mark this question as duplicate.